# How do I return Record when building it as Partial in function?

Tags: typescript, record, partial

How do I return `Record` when building it as `Partial` in the function bellow?

```
type mytype = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd';

function generate(): Record<mytype,any> {
    const p: Partial<Record<mytype, any>> = {};

    // some code which dynamically builds up 'p'

    return p;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> [ts]
>       Type 'Partial>' is not assignable to type 'Record'.
>         Property 'a' is optional in type 'Partial>' but required in type 'Record'.

**UPDATE:**
I found I can just do the following, but is it the correct way to do it?

```
return p as Record<mytype, any>;
```

Comment: If you're sure that the code which builds up `p` really adds all the properties, then it's *a* correct way to do it... you're giving up some type safety for ease of programming.  If you want TypeScript to guarantee type safety for you, you'd have to rewrite the code that builds up `p` to convince it.